# How to fix 'object' does not contain a constructor error when using ADO .NET Entity Data Model in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
namespace DataLayer
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Entities 
    {
        private Entities(DbConnection connectionString, bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
            : base(connectionString, contextOwnsConnection) { }
        public static Entities CreateEntities(bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
        {
            //Doc file connect
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fs = File.Open("connectdb.dba", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            connect cp = (connect)bf.Deserialize(fs);

            //Decrypt noi dung
            string servername = Encryptor.Decrypt(cp.servername, "qwertyuiop", true);
            string database = Encryptor.Decrypt(cp.database, "qwertyuiop", true);

            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = $"Data Source={servername};Initial Catalog={database};Integrated Security=true";
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/HOTEL.csdl|res://*/HOTEL.ssdl|res://*/HOTEL.msl";

            EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
            fs.Close();
            return new Entities(connection);
        }

    }
}
```

> Error CS1729
> 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments    DataLayer
> at :base(..)

Please help me to solve this error that error appeared as soon as I removed 1 ADO.NET Entity Data model and added another one

Comment: Does the base of Entities have a constructor with 2 parameters?

Comment: This error occurs when you either directly or indirectly invoke the constructor of base a class but the compiler cannot find any constructors with the same number of parameters